# Count the # of item displayed on Sap Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

Now I got 2 Sales Orders:
S018040553 and S018040850

S018040553 - has one item called Buzz Ottoman

S018040850 - has 2 items called Amelia and Charlotte

Update:
I've changed the code and added DistinctCount instead of Count but it doesn't still fix the issue :(

```
WhilePrintingRecords;NumberVar ItemNumber;ToText(ItemNumber, 0) & "/" & ToText(DistinctCount({rpt_PackingSlip.LineNo}, {rpt_PackingSlip.WorkOrderNo}),0)
```

I got the results below:
and the desired output are in "red" font.
[S018040553](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsRqD.jpg)

[image: S018040553]

[image: S018040850]

[image]

Comment: How's the report grouped? Can you add that information to your question? It seems that the `Count`-function points to the wrong group...`{rpt_PackingSlip.WorkOrderNo}` should probably be another column.

Comment: Instead of count take distinctcount

Comment: @MatSnow: I have updated the question :)

Comment: @srikanth: i have applied the change but still wont fix the issue. ive edited the question.

Comment: @TrishFernandez It's still not clear how the report is grouped. There are just previews with the (not) desired output. Please show the structure of the report (sections and groups).